# How to recover deleted/updated record in sql server or mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to know that is there any way that I can can recover the deleted or updated record in the sqlserver and mysql as well?

Comment: You should search google before asking here. Each part of your question has an existing duplicate: for SQL Server, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540729/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-sql-server-table and for MySQL look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql

Comment: from a backup...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always have a choice to use a recovery tools, such as ApexSQL Log for example. Not only that you can recover deleted rows, but you can also choose which rows you are going to recover.

It can recover your data from on-line, backup or detached transaction logs.

I have tried that tool and it could be the life saver.

See: [How to recover SQL Server data from accidental UPDATE and DELETE operations](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/2012/11/how-to-recover-sql-server-data-from.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you updated it and what backup/disaster recovery strategy you use.

If you are performing the `DELETE` within a `TRANSACTION`, the action can always be rolled-back until you `COMMIT` it.

Perhaps you're logging/auditing such operations using a trigger or similar, in which case you could find the data that was changed and do the 'opposite' to restore it.

Perhaps you're replicating the database every so often to another server - you could restore the data from there.

Perhaps you're performing backups to disk or tape in which case you might have to perform a full restore to get it back.

Failing all that - and short of forensic recovery - unless you can remember the data that was there, it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really think so. Once deleted, it gets deleted permanently...
This is a bit old, but haven't heard of anything else: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,135990,137776#msg-137776

Answer (score 0):

Once the row is deleted it is gone. You can will have to use a backup to restore the data.

The exceptions to this are if you are doing a delete inside an open [Transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), in those cases you can "Rollback" the transaction to undo any changes made inside the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this thread would be help you :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx

If the above url did not help you, you can try to recover this third party RecoveryFix for SQL Software. This software will restore data in working condition.

Thanks